# Combine digits with update query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to do a update query in MS Access.
The target table includes the column "tt" that is formated as integer and "000000".
The source table includes columns "a" and "b". Both contain integers <=999.
The first three digits of column "tt" should contain the digits of column "a",
the last three digits of column "tt" should contain the digits of column "b".

`Format([b];"000")` works fine and gives a result like 000111, but I do not manage to combine the values of column "a" and "b".

The following trials don't work:

```
ZInteger(Format([a];"000") & Format([b];"000"))

ZInteger( ZString(Format([a];"000")) & ZString(Format([b];"000")) )

(Format([a];"000")*1000) + Format([b];"000")
```

Comment: Please show your code in its original context - we don't know where or how you're calling `ZInteger` or `Format` - are you doing this entirely in VBA or is this a VBA call within JET Red SQL?

Comment: Integer is 16bit and too small for 6 digit numbers. Use CLong (ZLong in German).

Answer (score 1):

Formatting only applies to non-strings and consists of converting them to a `String` by applying some format. If `a` or `b` are `Text` columns containing a number, they do not count as `Integer`. The values to be formatted must really be of a numeric type if you want the `Format` function to have an effect on them.

You can have a result up to 999999 which does not fit in the ranges of integers (which are only 16 bit in VBA).  So, you will will need a `Long` to store the result as a number.

In your examples you covert the result back to an `Integer`. If you want the result to be a number why not just write (resulting in a `Long`)

```
1000 * a + b
```

If you want this to be formatted with leading zeroes, write

```
Format(1000 * CLng(a) + b, "000000")
```

Note that in the latter case, the result will be a `String`. Converting it to an `Long` would remove any leading zeroes.